# Deberíamos mejorar la descripción del sitio indicada en Help Center > Asking

Tags: discusión, ámbito

Spanish SE tiene tantos hablantes nativos del idioma como estudiantes de él. Con una comunidad compartida de este tipo sería especialmente importante clarificar quiénes somos y cuáles son las preguntas que nos interesan. Siendo estudiante yo mismo, tenía la duda de si se aceptarían preguntas sobre el aprendizaje del español.

Otras comunidades responden muy claramente a la pregunta con este *banner* de bienvenida:

[image]

Spanish SE no lo hace y además casi se contradice (fuente: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> El Spanish Language Stack Exchange es para lingüistas, etimologistas y entusiastas (serios) del idioma español. Las preguntas sobre los siguientes asuntos son bienvenidas:

La gente estudiando el idioma no parece incluida. Quizás bajo `entusiastas`, pero lo del ‘serios’ es intimidatorio: ¿soy yo un entusiasta serio con mi pregunta tonta sobre por qué se dice ‘les ayudo’ o ‘los ayudo’?

Pero en la lista de buenas preguntas hay esta:

> Problemas encontrados por la gente que está aprendiendo español

Pero un poco después en la de preguntas a no realizar:

> Preguntas buscando recursos de aprendizaje

Comprendo lo que quiere decir y parece que se responda a preguntas de estudiante, pero la búsqueda de una respuesta clara ya ha durado más de treinta minutos. No me sorprendería si una parte de la gente preferiría buscar sus respuestas en algún otro lugar.

¿Deberíamos hacer algo para hacer este punto más claro?

Comment: @walen ¡yo también lo TIL! También vale con `<s>`.

Comment: Nótese que la página https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic la podemos editar los moderadores (nos aparece un botoncillo `edit` debajo, como en las preguntas y respuestas). Por tanto, cualquier cambio aquí sería trivial, solamente hace falta consensuar el qué. El resto de páginas del centro de ayuda no podemos editarlas y debemos solicitarlo a un community manager de Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's that same banner but for Spanish.SE (you can only see it if you haven't closed it in a previous session):

[image]

"**Students, teachers, and linguists**". I think it is pretty inclusive, just like Aviation.SE's description.

Aviation.SE's "on-topic" section is also fairly similar:

> Aviation Stack Exchange is a site for pilots, controllers, mechanics, and aviation enthusiasts.

Comparing with the equivalent Spanish.SE site description:

> El Spanish Language Stack Exchange es para lingüistas, etimologistas y entusiastas (serios) del idioma español.

Not that much of a difference.
I agree with you **that "(serious)" remark seems a bit out-of-place, but that's it.**

Bear in mind also that we're talking about a piece of text most new users don't bother to read before asking :P
But yeah, it wouldn't do any harm to reword it and make it read like the Welcome banner.

---

About the "learning resources" part, it's been discussed several times.

First it was decided that it was off-topic.
Then it was decided that a Meta post would be created with a list of learning resources, so asking users could be told to check said Meta post.
Then the Meta post was perma-linked in the front page, so asking users could hopefully see it before asking.

I guess the next logical step would be to just make a canonical non-Meta question and use it to close questions as duplicated -- but such a question would itself be off-topic too, so nobody has dared to do it yet :)

Comment: There is no problem answering in english, specially in the meta site.

Comment: *you can only see it if you haven't closed it in a previous session* -- that sounds problematic.

Comment: "Students, teachers, and linguists" ≠ "lingüistas, etimologistas y entusiastas (serios) del idioma español".  Could we make it "estudiantes, maestros, y lingüistas"?

Comment: ¿Sería aficionados una palabra mejora?

Comment: ¿Abrimos pues un debate sobre el tener una pregunta canónica de recursos en el sitio principal?

Comment: @walen - Me gusta "entusiastas."

Answer (score 1):

For the Site Definition, @Walen proposed elsewhere starting off with "linguists" and I fear that make a fair number of people leery of participating.

Also, I'd like to see something like "all levels of Spanish skills are welcome." Perhaps:

> The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for anyone with an interest in Spanish, at any level, from raw beginner up to linguists and poets, and everything in between.

I do like the word "enthusiasts" and think it would be a good word to start off with.

In short, start with "enthusiasts" and omit "linguists."  It sounds too snobbish.  If we continue with our current level of rigor, the linguists will find us and be happy.

---

Slight variant thanks to @mdewey:

> The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for anyone with an interest in Spanish.

Another short and sweet one:

> The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for Spanish enthusiasts.

Comment: For me the less said the better so I might just say that up to "... at any level" and delete the examples. The problem with lists is that someone always feels left out and you end up with a list like an anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad, no sé por qué no se permiten

> Preguntas buscando recursos de aprendizaje

¿No sería más fácil simplemente cerrar las nuevas preguntas que se hagan sobre esto, por ya tener respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here is the description of different sites in their tour.

I must say I really likek the German option!!

[Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Russian Language and Usage is a question and answer site for people who are interested in studying or teaching Russian, as well as for enthusiast and curious native speakers.

[Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Japanese Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language.

[French](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)

> French Language is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language.

[German](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour)

> German Language and Usage is a bilingual question-and-answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language.

[Italian](https://italian.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Italian Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Italian language.

[Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Portuguese Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, teachers, and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language.