# ¿Qué extremos del off-topic deberíamos reconsiderar?

Tags: discusión, off-topic

Hace meses que estamos golpeando los límites del off-topic para ver si son pared maestra o más bien tabique.

Empezamos con lo de [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674), que venía a abordar el conflicto de la política de que [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Pero por favor, no preguntes sobre los siguientes asuntos. Están fuera del ámbito de este sitio.
>
> - ...
> - Preguntas sobre "listas", donde cada respuesta es igualmente válida
> - Preguntas buscando recursos de aprendizaje

Es decir, nos hemos dado cuenta de que hay preguntas que indudablemente tendrán respuestas igualmente válidas pues dependen de la región, por lo que no se puede determinar cuál es la buena, sino más bien incorporarlas en una respuesta única tipo wiki de comunidad.

Esto nos hace abrir la primera pregunta: ¿debemos aceptar preguntas cuyas respuestas sean del tipo lista? ¿Bajo qué condiciones? ¿Deberíamos circunscribirlo a etiquetas determinadas?

---

Pasado el tiempo, y relacionado con lo de arriba en cuanto a preguntas de listas, [empezamos a observar](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2710/1674) que la pregunta [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674) podría bien moverse al sitio principal para ejercer de pregunta canónica contra la que marcar como duplicadas las preguntas que consulten por recursos de aprendizaje, algo que más arriba hemos visto que también es [una de los motivos de cierre propios del sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2701/1674).
<sub>(También podemos dejar este tema para más adelante, y solamente apuntarlo para que se aborde en otra pregunta.)</sub>

---

Siguió el tiempo y el clímax (con cariño) vino con la pregunta [Una vez al año no hace daño: propuesta para permitir preguntas off-topic](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2725/1674) en la que se planteaba la posibilidad de hacer un día en el que valieran preguntas en el límite exterior del off-topic actual (es decir, actualmente consideradas como tal). Se comentó sobre preguntas del tipo opinión o futuribles (sobre normas, posibles evoluciones, reformas, etc) y tuvo varias posiciones a favor de ello.

---

Con todo, esto es solamente un intento de recopilar las iniciativas que han ido surgiendo por aquí para, con ello, abrir el debate y preguntaros a todos: ¿cuáles de las limitaciones por *off-topic* actualmente vigentes os parecen obsoletas? ¿Cuáles y bajo qué condiciones nosotros, como comunidad, podemos aceptar cambiar, manteniendo siempre el firme propósito de crear un sitio sano, útil y lo más riguroso posible?

¡Abran juego, señores!

Comment: @aparente001 observo un voto negativo y un voto para cerrar como demasiado amplio. Creo que más que obrar así es más productivo comentarlo abiertamente. Estamos en Meta, intentamos mejorar el sitio, seamos productivos.

Comment: @walen gracias por explicitar motivos, en este caso para mantenerla abierta. Como bien sabes, esta pregunta surgió después de meses de debate _guadianesco_ (ahora surge, ahora desaparece) sobre el límite del off topic. Para no preguntar sin más _¿Qué extremos del off topic deberíamos reconsiderar?_, decidí incluir algunos de esos posibles extremos para "rompler el hilo", en algo que bien podría haber sido una respuesta. Por tanto, la finalidad no era debatir sobre esos tres temas (lo cual sí sería demasiado genérico, mejor tres preguntas) sino hacer lluvia de ideas. No ha funcionado demasiado.

Answer (score 1):

Hace ya tiempo que las preguntas con respuestas de tipo lista se admiten en el sitio, con la única particularidad de que el mismo que pregunta debe abrir una respuesta en modo *community wiki* para que la gente pueda ir aglutinando ahí todas las respuestas posibles.

Recuerdo como ejemplo la primera pregunta que hice (inadvertidamente) de este tipo: *[Colección de expresiones usadas para decir "faltar a clase"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17020/12637)*. En aquel momento la pregunta no se cerró, pero tú mismo me avisaste de que contravenía las normas del sitio y procedí a crear la respuesta CW antes de llegaran las primeras respuestas de los usuarios, que serían todas igualmente válidas. Desde entonces se han formulado muchas otras preguntas similares, y todas han seguido el mismo camino.

No considero pues que estas preguntas sean *off-topic*, porque si hacemos estas preguntas es por el simple hecho de que nuestro idioma permite este tipo de preguntas (dada la cantidad de variedades regionales que tenemos), y no debemos ignorar este hecho ni convertirlo en algo *off-topic*.

Una idea que se me ocurre es tener tres secciones:

- Sección *off-topic*: en esta sección debemos incluir los tipos de preguntas que no queremos hacer bajo ningún concepto.
- Sección *preguntas peculiares* (se admiten sugerencias para cambiar el nombre de la sección): añadimos aquí las preguntas que se pueden hacer pero que necesitan hacerse de una forma concreta. Por ejemplo, las preguntas del TG necesitan ser automáticamente convertidas a CW, y las preguntas con respuestas de tipo lista necesitan que el autor de la pregunta cree una respuesta en modo CW donde ir incorporando respuestas parciales.
- Sección *preguntas estándar*: todo el resto de preguntas posibles.

---

Con respecto a las preguntas acerca de recursos: veo bien mover la pregunta sobre recursos para aprender español al sitio principal, marcarla como pregunta canónica, y las preguntas similares marcarlas como duplicadas en vez de cerrarlas. Así abrimos la posibilidad de preguntar por otro tipo de recursos más específicos, como "¿qué diccionarios hay que se especialicen en términos científicos?". ¿Qué haríamos con estas preguntas? ¿Marcarlas como duplicadas y añadir una nueva sección en la pregunta canónica? ¿O permitir que se desarrollen por su cuenta?

Lo único malo que le veo a esto es que ya no podríamos marcarla como *featured* y dejaría de aparecer en el cuadro a la derecha, donde creo que tiene buena visibilidad.

---

Por último, también me parecería correcto relajar (o incluso eliminar) las restricción sobre las preguntas que se resuelvan con una simple búsqueda al diccionario. Igual que alguien puede no conocer el recurso del [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu), un principiante de español puede que no sepa que existe la RAE y que tiene un diccionario en línea. Por tanto, podría preguntar qué significa una palabra que igual para nosotros es fácil pero para él no lo es. En vez de borrarle la pregunta, se le explica lo que significa y se le redirige a la pregunta de recursos para aprender español, o incluso directamente al propio diccionario.

Lo normal es que en cuanto un usuario vea que tiene el recurso a su alcance deje de hacer preguntas de ese tipo, dado que él mismo las considerará triviales. El único problema es que llegue un *trol* y empiece a hacer preguntas de este tipo constantemente. Ya queda a elección de cada uno responderlas o no. Quién sabe, igual así animamos a la gente con poca reputación a responder si ve que son preguntas más asequibles, y puede que así fomentemos la participación.

Comment: The only problem I foresee with requiring the author of a question which gives rise to a list to mark it as CW is that s/he has to be able to predict in advance that there will be so many different responses.

Comment: We should not under-estimate how difficult it can be for an L1 English speaker to do web searches in Spanish however skilled s/he may be at doing it in English.

Comment: Veo que mi pregunta es tan genérica que la respuesta necesariamente debe tener tres bloques. Bueno, esta puede ser una pregunta-sondeo-consultivo y luego decidiremos tema a tema :) De acuerdo con el tema 1, sí tenemos preguntas que son listado sí o sí; solo falta marcar exactamente cuáles y lo de usar CW parece lo más práctico. Tema 2: podría consultar si tienen datos de cuánta gente aprieta en "Resources for learning Spanish", pero sí parece difícil conseguir tanta visibilidad como hasta ahora. Tema 3: tengo mis dudas, puede que no indicar diccionario, pero sí mostrar esfuerzo de algún tipo.

Comment: @walen I was thinking of someone whose search leads, say, to the _Nueva gramática de la lengua española_ and is then faced with pages of text in Spanish. It is not easy to scan these for meaning unless you are already fairly fluent and have some grasp of the grammatical terms in Spanish.

Comment: @walen me parece que el tema tiene suficiente chicha como para plantearlo en una discusión aparte, ¿te parece? Y así estudiamos todos los pros y contras. Lo abro en las próximas semanas, pero si quieres ábrelo tú. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @walen esta respuesta plantea unas dudas sobre mover la respuesta de Resources. Las he indicado en [mi respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2742/1674) a tu propuesta. ¿Has meditado al respecto? Parece que la propuesta prospera pero ahora mismo necesita pulido.

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría una forma de definir si las preguntas o respuestas van dirigidas hacia hispanoamericanos o ibéricos.

He visto la reacción ante mis respuestas e indagando me di cuenta que algunos términos que he utilizado no son ni remotamente utilzados en España. Sin embargo, la definición es la misma.

O, en muchas otras ocasiones, las preguntas se ven afectadas por regionalismos, modismos y opiniones y no tienen una respuesta única.

Obviamente para algunos, la mitad de las respuestas resultan perfectas y para otros confusas.

El español es un idioma oficial en 20 paises a través de tres continentes, y aunque es una regla de Stack Overflow, la verdad encuentro de extremo mal gusto los puntos negativos sin una justificación.

Una comunidad no se puede enriquecer únicamente diciendo que algo está mal sin dar razones.

Comment: Mike, tu respuesta a partir del segundo párrafo no sé si está especialmente dirigida a mi pregunta. Aparte de incurrir en múltiples faltas ortográficas, resulta complicado seguir el hilo argumental de lo que expones. Sugiero qu leas [help] con detenimiento para tener una visión más clara del sitio, seguro que tus contribuciones serán de mucha ayuda con un poco de pulido. Gracias y bienvenido.

Comment: @walen - Estoy de acuerdo que hay que mantener las normas de ortografía, etc., pero me parece que por lo general si se da un voto negativo, se debe dar feedback.  Sugiero que guardes el texto en alguna parte de tu computadora (por ejemplo con un Clipboard Manager) para que sea más cómodo dar el comentario.