# ¿Podemos mejorar nuestra página "What topics can I ask about here" con respecto a las traducciones?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, centro-de-ayuda

Nuestra página ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) no menciona nada de las traducciones.  Creo que hay consenso de que si muestra uno cierto esfuerzo, se permite pedir ayuda con expresar cierta idea o concepto en español.

Los invito a redactar algo para agregar a la página de Help.

Comment: Actualmente estamos debatiendo [¿Qué extremos del off-topic deberíamos reconsiderar?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2732/1674). Una vez eso esté determinado, será interesante abordar esta pregunta y ver cómo explicamos el nivel de esfuerzo solicitado.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el tipo de ayuda que aceptamos ofrecer actualmente, se engloba en la descripción del penúltimo punto:

- Usos, elección de palabras, gramática (...)

Cuando alguien pide ayuda con una traducción, dentro de los límites que solemos aceptar, suele ser para confirmar si una construcción está bien usada, o para ayudar a elegir una palabra o frase concreta para expresar un concepto, o para validar si los tiempos verbales u otros aspectos gramaticales son correctos.
Creo que esos casos están cubiertos por el punto anterior.

No obstante lo dicho, sí que echo de menos por mi parte que la referencia a "traducciones" que sí que tenemos, sea un poco más clara; concretamente:

> Pero por favor, no preguntes sobre los siguientes asuntos. Están fuera del ámbito de este sitio.
>
> - Otros idiomas diferentes del español (incluyendo traducciones).

Personalmente lo cambiaría a "... traducciones *del español a otros idiomas*". Esto también ayudaría a aclarar que traducciones de otros idiomas a español sí que podrían aceptarse, siempre que respeten el resto de criterios.

Comment: Me parece bien. Ponlo mejor en otra pregunta para que quede bien documentadito y con sus correspondientes etiquetas, así más gente lo ve y puede matizar la propuesta. Por mí está bien.

Comment: @fedorqui - Creo que no es necesario redactar una nueva pregunta, si edito mi título un poquito.

Comment: Walen, propongo un pequeño cambio: *Otros idiomas diferentes del español (incluyendo traducciones **del español** a otro idioma).*

Comment: @aparente001 ¡buena idea!

Comment: @walen - Perdón, de veras no me quedó claro.  Me fijé en lo que tenía fondo gris.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @walen's proposal, I would like to add a bullet point in the "Questions on the following topics are welcome here" section.  I'm flexible about the wording but here's the idea:

> - Translation of a particular expression or concept **to Spanish** (but note, you must show your research)
> - Traducción de cierta expresión o concepto **al español** (pero pero recuerda que debes indicar qué has intentado)

I would not like this bullet point added at the end of the list, because that would be more noticeable and might over-encourage participants to ask for help with translation.

Comment: Something like _pero recuerda que debes indicar qué has intentado_.