# Proposal: make clear that the off-topic "translations" are "translations *from* Spanish to X"

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, ámbito, centro-de-ayuda

> <sub>This is a [feature-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) post.
>
>   **Upvoting** it means you **agree** with the proposal.
>
>   **Downvoting** it means you **disagree** with the proposal.
>
>   You can answer or comment if you want, but you don't need to.</sub>

---

Following [fedorqui's advice](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/podemos-mejorar-nuestra-p%C3%A1gina-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-con-respecto/2832#comment4827_2830), I officially request for the text of ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this item specifically:

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics (...)
>
> - Languages other than Spanish (including translation)

To be rewritten as follows:

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics (...)
>
> - Languages other than Spanish (including translations from Spanish to other languages).

This is to make it a bit more clear that asking for translations *to* Spanish is allowed, as long as they adhere to the other criteria (show effort, specific question...).

---

Siguiendo [la recomendación de fedorqui](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/podemos-mejorar-nuestra-p%C3%A1gina-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-con-respecto/2832#comment4827_2830), propongo oficialmente cambiar en ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) la redacción de este punto:

> Pero por favor, no preguntes sobre (...)
>
> - Otros idiomas diferentes del español (incluyendo traducciones).

Para dejarlo así:

> Pero por favor, no preguntes sobre (...)
>
> - Otros idiomas diferentes del español (incluyendo traducciones del español a otros idiomas).

Esto es para dejar un poco más claro que pedir traducciones *al* español sí que está permitido, siempre que se respeten el resto de criterios (esfuerzo previo, duda concreta...).

Comment: Could you add some bolding and adjust number as follows?  Languages other than Spanish (including translations **from** Spanish **to** some other language).

Comment: Es decir, que no traducimos **del** español **a** otros idiomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change has been done and it is live in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

<sub>I am answering saying "I did it" instead of just marking the question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because OP noticed that this way the question will still show in the Unanswered tab. Let's upvote [Remove questions with moderator tags from the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65429/209901) to have this behaviour changed.</sub>

Comment: I went there and upvoted as you requested.  But this request is so buried here it might not get much of a result.  Perhaps you could create a separate, targeted Meta post.

Comment: @aparente001 you can also place a bounty in that question so it gets more attention.