# Proposal: specify that "translations *to* Spanish" are on-topic

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, ámbito, centro-de-ayuda

> <sub>This is a [feature-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) post.
>
> **Upvoting** it means you **agree** with the proposal.
>
> **Downvoting** it means you **disagree** with the proposal.
>
> You can answer or comment if you want, but you don't need to.</sub>

---

*This is a stand-alone proposal taken from an [answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2832/9385) posted earlier by aparente001.  I am posting it here as that user worded it.*

In addition to [@walen's proposal](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/proposal-make-clear-that-the-off-topic-translations-are-translations-from-sp), I would like to add a bullet point in the "Questions on the following topics are welcome here" section.  I'm flexible about the wording but here's the idea:

> - Translation of a particular expression or concept **to Spanish** (but note, you must show your research)
> - Traducción de cierta expresión o concepto **al español** (pero recuerda que debes indicar qué has intentado)

I would not like this bullet point added at the end of the list, because that would be more noticeable and might over-encourage participants to ask for help with translation.

Comment: General discussion of wording, placement, etc., is welcome.

Comment: I endorse walen's proposal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change has been done and it is live in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Note I replaced the bold format **al español** for *al español* in italics, since there is just one piece of bold text in the whole page and this was giving unnecessary priority to a specific part of a sentence.

<sub>I am answering saying "I did it" instead of just marking the question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because OP noticed that this way the question will still show in the Unanswered tab. Let's upvote [Remove questions with moderator tags from the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65429/209901) to have this behaviour changed.</sub>

Comment: Thank you fedorqui but could you please move it up so it's not at the end of the list?  Remember I wrote, "I would not like this bullet point added at the end of the list, because that would be more noticeable and might over-encourage participants to ask for help with translation."

Comment: @aparente001 you are right, I overlooked that part. I have updated it.

Comment: Thank you, it looks really good.