# Proposal: change site description to "Linguists, teachers, students and enthusiasts"

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, ámbito

> This is a [feature-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) post.
>   **Upvoting** it means you **agree** with the proposal.
>   **Downvoting** it means you **disagree** with the proposal.
>   You can answer or comment if you want, but you don't need to.

**Proposal**:
Change the site description to make it more inclusive, as proposed in [this answer and its comments](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2710/13628). The specific proposed translations to Spanish and English are included below.

**Motivation**:
The site's description as found in the [Help > Asking > On-topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section, currently reads like this:

- *The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) Spanish-language enthusiasts.* (English)
- *Spanish Language Stack Exchange es para lingüistas, etimologistas y entusiastas (serios) del idioma español.* (Spanish)

This seems a bit too elitist, compared to the description featured in the banner shown to unregistered users, which is currently:

- *Spanish Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists (...).*

After all this years, it's pretty clear that this site is not *only* for linguists, etymologists and "serious" enthusiasts. Students and teachers are welcome too.
So I propose for both descriptions to be changed to this:

- **The Spanish Language Stack Exchange** is for linguists, teachers, students and Spanish language enthusiasts in general. (English)
- **Spanish Language Stack Exchange** es para lingüistas, docentes, estudiantes y entusiastas en general del idioma español. (Spanish)

**Spanish TL;DR**:
Cambiar y unificar la descripción del sitio en las distintas secciones, usando el texto arriba propuesto, para hacerla más inclusiva y acorde a los usuarios reales que tenemos.

---

The above proposal has been discussed already on Meta and/or chat, but apparently a consensus has not been reached, because of low participation I guess.

[image]

That being the case, I'm opening an official [feature-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) post, so you can just upvote or downvote the proposal. Maybe we can get more users to participate this way.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, por lo que voto a favor de ello. Gracias por traer el debate, sugiero dejarlo abierto unos diez díasa para maximizar la atención que pueda recibir. Le añado [meta-tag:featured].

Comment: Have voted to close as a duplicate of [Deberíamos mejorar la descripción del sitio indicada en Help Center > Asking](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/deber%c3%adamos-mejorar-la-descripci%c3%b3n-del-sitio-indicada-en-help-center-asking)

Comment: @aparente001 creo que estás dificultando el trabajo en Meta. ¿Tenemos una propuesta concreta abierta, se está votando y votas por cerrarla como duplicada de una anterior, muy genérica y que hace meses que estaba parada?

Comment: Con 5 votos a favor y 1 en contra, damos por buena la votación y procedemos a cambiar el texto en [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @walen tienes razón. Lo consulto, pues no veo cómo puede un moderador modificar esta parte.

Comment: @walen escribí a los CM, te aviso cuando tenga respuesta.

Comment: Totalmente a favor de cualquier iniciativa para parecer menos elitistas, porque a veces incluso los nativos alucinamos con las preguntas que se hacen aquí, no quiero ni imaginarme un estudiante de español.... ;)

Comment: @walen los CM me dijeron ayer por la noche que ya está hecho. En cuanto se haga un build, funcionará. Démosle un par de días.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con 5 votos a favor y 1 en contra, damos por buena la votación y procedemos a cambiar el texto en [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

También se ha modificado el texto que aparece en el encabezado de la página cuando no tenemos una sesión iniciada. Como esto sale de [¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674), han sido los CM los que lo han hecho (Shog9 en particular → thanks!).

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I support the basic idea but I think the wording needs work.  Starting off with "linguists" might turn a lot of people off.

Also, I'd like to see something like "all levels of Spanish skills are welcome."  Perhaps:

> The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for anyone with an interest in Spanish, at any level, from raw beginner up to linguists and poets, and everything in between.