# ¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?

Tags: soporte, faq, moderación

Últimamente están apareciendo muy interesantes propuestas para mejorar la documentación. A medida que aparecen, los moderadores investigamos hasta dónde llegan las herramientas que tenemos disponibles, para ver si podremos implantar nosotros mismos lo que proponéis o si, por contra, deberemos solicitarlo a algún empleado de Stack Exchange.

Cuando es algo a nuestro alcance, el tiempo entre la aceptación de una propuesta y su materialización es muy breve. Por contra, cuando escapa de nuestro control debemos considerar que los CMs ven este sitio como una cosa muy pequeña :)

El propósito pues de esta pregunta-respuesta es mantener un listado de qué podemos modificar los moderadores, para el conocimiento de todos y mejor explicación de qué está a nuestro alcance. Lo que no está listado es porque o bien solo pueden modificarlo los CM, o bien directamente no se puede modificar.

English version in [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/209901)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Documentación

### [Centro de ayuda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help)

- El texto en [What topics can I ask about here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Entero.
- El texto que encabeza el Centro de ayuda, que ahora mismo está vacío en este sitio.

> [image]

Hay sitios, como Buddhism, que tienen bastante información allí:

> [image]

### [Tour](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour)

Diferentes secciones.

- El encabezado, ahora consistente en:

> **Spanish Language Stack Exchange** is a bilingual question and answer site for linguists, teachers, students and Spanish language enthusiasts in general wanting to discuss the finer points of the language. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the Spanish language.

- *Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*.

La pregunta de ejemplo.

- *Get answers to practical, detailed questions*

Los puntos en *Ask about...* y *Don't ask about...*.

---

También podemos modificar:

- las opciones de cierre por *off-topic*.

Comment: Sí muy buena idea, el problema es más el contenido que vamos a introducir en esas secciones