# Do we have a Spanish version of "How to ask"?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Do we have a Spanish version of [How to ask/Asking help](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Do we want to have one?  (I'm thinking yes.)

There are actually two things here.  One is the *page* and the other is the pink box that pops up when you start to draft a question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this Help page, and probably all of them, should be also in Spanish. To launch Stack Overflow en español all these contents were translated, so it would be just a matter of copying them here.

As seen in [¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674), this is a page moderators cannot edit, so we would need to ask a [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/209901) to do so.

Regarding the pink box that pops up when you start to draft a question, I do think that it is a great resource we are not using enough, so we could probably brainstorm what could fit well in there (for example, a link to Resources... would be helpful).