# Pregunta para los mods actuales: ¿qué supone para vosotros ser moderador de Spanish.SE?

Tags: discusión, moderación, elecciones, moderadores

Imagino que algunos de los usuarios con más experiencia o nivel de participación en el sitio se estarán planteando si presentar su candidatura en [las elecciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/1) o no.
Algunas de las preguntas que quizá se estén haciendo puede que sean: si fuera mod, ¿qué podría hacer, que ahora no pueda? Y ¿qué no podría hacer, que ahora sí puedo? ¿De qué manera cambiará mi relación con el sitio?

O, resumiendo mucho: **¿qué se gana y qué se pierde al convertirse en mod?**

**Diego, fedorqui**: Como moderadores *pro tem* nombrados tras llevar varios años en el sitio, estoy seguro de que podéis dar un punto de vista muy útil sobre esto. ¿Cuál ha sido vuestra experiencia?

**Flimzy, Joze**: creo que vosotros fuisteis los primeros moderadores, vuestro punto de vista será obviamente distinto, pero por supuesto estaría genial si lo podéis compartir también :)

---

Diego, fedorqui: gracias por vuestra honesta respuesta. Lo único que puedo decir es: ¡qué suerte teneros a los dos como moderadores!

Comment: Gracias por la pregunta. La verdad es que le estaba comentando a fedorqui, literalmente ayer, publicar esto mismo, para que la gente que no sabe si presentarse o no sepa a en qué consiste ser mod, cuánto tiempo le dedicamos, etc. Luego me leo el tochazo de fedoprqui y pongo una publicación propia, si procede.

Answer (score 6):

La lista de *competencias* de un moderador está bien explicada en:

[Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/209901), cuya traducción al castellano puede encontrarse en Meta SOes: [¿Quién son los moderadores ♦? ¿Cuál es su rol?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4029/83) (la traduje yo, de hecho). Sugiero dar un buena lectura al tema, que complementa lo también indicado en [¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674). También es bueno echar una ojeada al artículo del Centro de Ayuda [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

Para quien quiera indagar más, es bueno leer también [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118972/209901) y [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119111/209901). Todas ellas son referencias que como moderador vas aprendiendo con el tiempo, recordando con el uso y comentando con los otros moderadores.

---

En cuanto a la visión más personal, antes de nada, creo que los moderadores actuales estamos haciendo bastante más de lo esencialmente necesario. Esto ocurre porque Diego y yo además de moderadores somos usuarios frecuentes con bastante inquietud y supongo que ese es el motivo por el que nos eligieron como *Pro Tem*. Por eso, muchas iniciativas que proponemos bien podríamos haberlas expuesto como usuarios *de a pie*. Sin ir más lejos, en Stack Overflow en español buena parte de las traducciones de contenido de las FAQ las he hecho yo, así como muchas peticiones al CM y sugerencias en general. Todo como usuario de a pie. No lo digo para darme golpes en el pecho, sino para constatar que un usuario normal puede crear mucho, sin necesidad de tener un diamante al lado de su nombre.
Creo que en este sitio somos pocos y con demasiada frecuencia se espera el visto bueno de los moderadores para hacer lo que está genial que se proponga directamente.

> ¿Qué se gana?

Os contaré un secreto: la red Stack Exchange me encanta. Al poco de descubrirla me puse a leer y leer debates en Meta, entradas del blog de Jeff Atwood y todo lo que hablara del sistema. Me encantó la idea, la transparencia y la capacidad de mejorarla con el recurso de la palabra. Stack Exchange es un entorno para preguntas y respuestas que, para mí, revoluciona la forma de interactuar en internet y lo hace mejor. Por ello, creo que ser moderador me ayuda a devolverle parte de lo que me ha enseñado, teniendo más cerca a la gente que toma decisiones, más información de algunos aspectos y sugiriendo mejoras con datos más fundamentados.
Cuando descubrí Spanish.SE me pareció que el sitio era algo flojo, bastaba con respuestas modestas para acumular buena reputación. Con el tiempo fui viendo más y más usuarios potentes, que con el tiempo han ido sedimentando un nivel bastante bueno, no ya para gente que aprende el idioma sino para hablantes nativos con dudas interesantes. De ahí que mi puesto de moderador me pareció una buena plataforma para acelerar la canonización de etiquetas, maneras de proceder, editar, etc.

Al ser moderador se gana en responsabilidad y herramientas. Se pueden hacer cosas más rápidamente (etiquetas, borrar comentarios, bloquear publicaciones, migrar preguntas...).

También se gana a nivel humano: una de las mejores experiencias de mi paso por la red Stack Exchange es haber conocido en profundidad a Diego, haber compartido dudas y debates con él, apreciado y aprendido de su forma de proceder y agradecido las veces que su pausa me ayudó a ver las cosas de otra forma, a la postre mejores.

Se gana también acceso a un chat de moderadores de toda la red, donde da gusto estar para aprender de ellos y sus experiencias, en todos los sentidos. También se gana acceso a un grupo (*Team*) para moderadores. En ambos casos también están [los CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/209901), que son empleados de la empresa y que tienen muy en cuenta a los moderadores (otra cosa es que otros departamentos también los tengan y que la empresa ponga recursos para mejorar, si bien parece que últimamente está mejorando).

> ¿Qué se pierde?

Despreocupación. A mí se me hace difícil como moderador entrar al sitio e interactuar sin más, pues tener el diamante ♦ conlleva, en cierta medida, no solo hablar en nombre propio sino prácticamente en representación del sitio. Por tanto, te obliga a tener más pausa y prudencia. Donde antes (o en otros sitios) votaría por cerrar más alegremente, ahora debo pararme para comentar, interactuar más, etc.

Cuando eres moderador, siempre ves arriba un numerito en azul que corresponde a los reportes pendientes de resolver. A mí me gusta tenerlo a cero, pero hay muchas ocasiones en las que es mejor esperar a que la comunidad se empodere y lo resuelva ella misma (*not an answer*, *low quality*... se acaban resolviendo con las colas, pero normalmente tardan bastante). Por tanto, el cargo de moderador también implica una dosis de paciencia y de espera: esperar a que un usuario nuevo edite su publicación algo floja, esperar a que recapacite un usuario que se ha calentado un poco, etc.

También se pierde en tranquilidad. Hay situaciones que cargan, usuarios que son desagradables y que la toman contigo. Incluso me atrevería a decir que hay gente mala y con ganas de hacer perder el tiempo a los otros. Por suerte, no ocurre con demasiada frecuencia en el sitio.

Como resumen, diría que ser moderador es un entretenimiento que puede ocupar alguna hora a la semana, repartida en distintos momentos. Requiere investigación y paciencia y permite conocer un poco mejor el sistema e interactuar con otra gente de una forma más cercana.

Comment: Deduzco por todo esto que la paciencia es una cualidad importante a tener en cuenta en los candidatos.

Answer (score 4):

Voy a describir un poco mi día a día como mod y unos cuantos pensamientos para ver si eso arroja un poco de luz sobre a qué se compromete un mod y en qué consiste para mí hacer de mod. A ver si con eso se anima más gente a presentarse.

Esta respuesta complementa la de Fedorqui. Estoy de acuerdo en las cosas que dice que un moderador gana y pierde frente al resto de usuarios.

Para empezar, a las tareas de moderación les puedes dedicar el tiempo que quieras. Está claro que como "usuario regular" le puedes dedicar tanto o tan poco tiempo al stack como quieras o puedas. Como mod, nada te obliga a atender las tareas de moderación. Simplemente se entiende que si aceptas el puesto es porque te comprometes a no desatenderlas y a compaginarlas con tu actividad como "usuario regular".

Dicho esto, aunque ha habido algún pico de trabajo, estas tareas no suelen llevar mucho tiempo en nuestro stack.

Como indica fedorqui, hay un contador para flags:
[image: contador para flags]

y si sigues el enlace llegas a una página con herramientas para moderador

[image]

En esa imagen falta una pestaña "links" que te lleva a una página con enlaces útiles para mods.

Esos flags pueden ser alertas de usuarios u otros flags regulares ("not an answer", "low quality", etc.) y estos tendemos a no resolverlos (por lo menos no muy rápido) para que la comunidad lo haga en las colas de revisión. Ya sabéis que los mods intentamos no hacer uso del *binding vote* si no es necesario (lo que incluye también no cerrar o reabrir preguntas de manera unilateral si no hay una razón de peso para ello).

Menciono esto porque, como ya indica Fedorqui, es posible que el puesto de mod sea atractivo para gente interesada en tareas de moderación y, paradójicamente, en muchos casos nos abstenemos de "moderar" cuando pensamos que le estamos robando la oportunidad a la comunidad de resolver estas cuestiones de la manera habitual (aunque lleve un poco más de tiempo). **Los mods perdemos un poco de acción en las colas de revisión**.

Una de las mejores partes del trabajo para mí es el chat de mods, porque (por lo menos hasta ahora) es un canal directo y exclusivo para hablar con Fedorqui, con quien da gusto trabajar. En ese chat solemos discutir algunas cosas relativas a moderación y otras más relativas al área de Meta. Discutimos por ejemplo cómo vemos la comunidad, si conviene intervenir en algo o esperar, si tenemos alguna idea para darle *vidilla* al stack... No es ningún secreto (ni ninguna sorpresa) que los actuales mods estamos entre los usuarios más activos de meta, pero quizá sí lo sea que a veces nos gusta hacer cosas (promover un cambio o una mejora) sin que se sepa que los mods estamos detrás de ellas, pues sabemos que cuando el cambio se percibe como paulatino y natural, la comunidad tiende a adoptarlos y mantenerlos mejor.

Las cualidades de un buen moderador las define la comunidad. Hay cualidades que todos esperamos en el resto de usuarios, y los moderadores simplemente intentamos ser exigentes con nosotros mismos al respecto y predicar con el ejemplo. Intentamos ser justos, pacientes, tener mano izquierda en el trato...  Fedorqui y yo nunca resolvemos flags contra nosotros mismos. Siempre avisamos al otro sin influenciarle para que lo resuelva y nos pedimos ayuda el uno al otro cuando empezamos a perder la paciencia en algo para que el otro nos ayude a encontrar el balance.

Diría también que ser moderador no te da estatus, pero eso es algo que me tendríais que confirmar vosotros. Quizá un usuario muy nuevo un poco *dependolado* haga caso a las instrucciones de un mod para no arriesgarse a una sanción (aunque los hay que desafían a cualquiera), pero imagino que los más veteranos miran más la trayectoria en la participación que el diamantito o lo que se pueda hacer con él. No creo que el resto de los usuarios te haga más caso por ser moderador.

Así que  ¿quién creo que disfrutaría o sacaría provecho (digamos *crecimiento personal*) de ejercer de moderador?

En mi experiencia (sé que muchos hemos llegado aquí a través de Stack Overflow; no sé si esto se cumple para profesionales de otros dominios) a medida que vas subiendo por la jerarquía de competencia en tu entorno laboral tus responsabilidades cambian un poco no solo a producir más y mejor, sino a mejorar el propio entorno de producción y gestionarlo incluso. Por ejemplo: hacer de mentor de miembros menos veteranos, asegurarse de que se respetan y mejoran las buenas prácticas (detectar y resolver problemas, revisar dónde estamos fallando para mejorarlo y qué estamos haciendo bien para promoverlo, y asegurarnos en general de que cada vez trabajamos mejor y de manera más inteligente), y a veces incluso poner paz o ayudar a encontrar el balance entre opiniones enfrentadas.

Ser un buen moderador es parecido. Debes querer participar en resolver los problemas, para asegurarte de que se resuelven de manera correcta y para que la gente aprenda a hacerlo y no te necesite.

Ser moderador podría ser un trabajo administrativo sin más: "veo un flag --> lo resuelvo lo mejor que sepa. Mi participación en Meta o el sitio principal son independientes de esta tarea". Pero ese enfoque es meramente burocrático.

**Ser moderador es, en mi opinión, para aquellos que quieran cargarse con un poquito más de responsabilidad y liderar con el ejemplo en mejorar la experiencia de los usuarios en el stack**. Idealmente un moderador es activo en Meta, pues es dónde hay que traer las cosas a mejorar que está viendo al resolver flags y conflictos.

Un moderador deber querer interactuar de forma activa con la comunidad, aunque, cuando haces las cosas bien, la gente no sabe si has intervenido o no, y las cosas simplemente van bien. Por eso a veces incluso hay que sacar a la comunidad un poco de esa zona de "No acción" y desafiarles con nuevas ideas o propuestas de mejora.

Cierto que mucho de esto se puede hacer como usuario normal, pero pienso que un buen moderador quiere ir más lejos y se involucra como mod para, más allá de resolver/administrar flags, **tomar acción** sobre las cosas que ve como posibles de mejora.

Como se dice de los *Scrum Masters*, un moderador deber ser un "*servant leader*" de su comunidad.

Comment: «Cuando haces las cosas bien, la gente no sabe si has intervenido o no». Eso mismo le decía Dios a Bender el el capitulo *Un dios entre nosotros* de Futurama. Creo que es la clave de un buen moderador aunque los demás puedan pensar que no dais ni golpe xD.

Comment: No, sí, cuando la comunidad respeta a un moderador por lo que ha observado de sus acciones y forma de tratar a la gente a lo largo del tiempo, entonces sí, lo que dice el moderador respetado lleva más peso.  Yo en lo personal aprecio bastante a los moderadores de este sitio pero para decir verdad, Colleen, moderadora de ELL, es una diosa.  A mi aviso. // ¿Entrono debería ser entorno?  Iba a editar eso pero luego lo ví una segunda vez y empecé a dudar.