# This is it! Gracias por todo. Renuncio al cargo de moderador (fedorqui)

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Estimados compañeros de fatigas, intereses, curiosidades y demás:

**He solicitado mi baja como moderador de este sitio.** Seguiré participando en el sitio pero como usuario.

Hace tres años y medio recibí con alegría y respeto el encargo de ser moderador de este sitio. Con el tiempo ambas se han acentuado: es muy reconfortante pensar que las herramientas que ofrece SE a los moderadores ayudan a hacerlo mejor; a la vez, tener un diamante al lado del nombre de usuario es una carga que a veces pesa demasiado e impide participar .

A medio camino entre usuario de a pie y la empresa, como moderador en los últimos tiempos he sentido que los intereses de ambos han ido divergiendo.  Siento que la filosofía inicial de Stack Overflow se está yendo al garete a medida que la empresa se va profesionalizando. Ya no somos gente con quien construir, sino cada vez más un resultado de unas cuentas de beneficios.

Como moderador he tenido el privilegio de poder ver de cerca el proceso y lamentar la deriva. Incluso ahora tengo la fe de que los CM que tanto admiro acabarán imponiéndose y volveremos al toque más humano, realmente humano. Sin embargo, siento que SE ahora es menos humano y apoya menos a los moderadores. Siento que se está dejando ir a mucho talento sin que se haga nada relevante para corregirlo. Por ello hace unas cuantas semanas [suspendí mi actividad como moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334062/209901).

Pero no solo es eso.

Siento que los últimos tiempos me han dejado emocionalmente exhausto. En medio de [la marejada en toda la red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/209901), no he podido o no he sabido qué hacer para que nuestro sitio, Spanish.SE, estuviera pacífico. Marchó guifa, dimitió Diego, se va walen... y siento que en cada uno de los casos podría haber hecho más para que no sucediera.

Mi curiosidad y voluntad de hacer mejor el sitio chocan con cierta impotencia ante situaciones lamentables y lamentadas. [Sigo sintiendo que la tarea de moderar es fantástica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3173/1674). Creo además que si no soy parte de la solución, debería evitar ser parte del problema.

Por ello, creo que lo mejor es dejar de ser moderador.

- Agradezco enormemente a SE la confianza que depositó en mí.
- A Diego tengo ganas de conocerlo en persona y darle un enorme abrazo. Muchos momentos compartidos, muchas cosas aprendidas de él. Cierta nostalgia.
- A Charlie me sabe mal no poder *disfrutarlo* más como co-moderador. Estoy convencido de que su maestría preguntando y respondiendo se hará extensiva a su manera de moderar.
- Al resto de la comunidad (blonfu, walen, DGaleano, aparente, pablo... ¡sois tantos!). Gracias por colaborar en la moderación, por aportar ideas, por ofrecer lo mejor de vosotros.
- A los moderadores de los otros stack: hay gente muy buena allí afuera. Añoraré veros de cerca para aprender día tras día.

Comment: Es una autentica pena que SE esté dejando escapar a personas que tanto han hecho por las distintas comunidades de la red. Por mi parte,un placer haber compartido el honor de ser moderador durante un breve tiempo, y espero seguir contando con tu excelente participación,sugerencias y ayuda en [es.so]. Un abrazo y seguimos en contacto ;)

Comment: Eres de los usuarios que más admiraba (y admiro) cuando entré en la red SE y especialmente en SOes. No por tu conocimiento en programación si no por tu compañerismo, incansable ayuda, respeto ...  Cuando se hicieron las elecciones en SOes dudaba en presentarme puesto que tenía muchas ganas de ayudar pero también grandes referentes como tú. Y tú me propusiste en meta como un gran candidato. Con eso lo tuve claro. Entiendo muy de cerca tus razones para marchar ya que es algo que nos afecta a todos los que nos preocupe el sitio y los usuarios. Muchas gracias por todo. Un gran abrazo, compañero.

Comment: Desde que llegué aquí me pareció una comunidad fantástica y me he sentido como en casa y creo que una parte de que este stack sea lo que es y cómo es es gracias a ti. A los moderadores anteriores que se retiraron al salir de beta no los conocí y con Diego he interactuado poco pero a ti te conozco un poco más, creo que has hecho mucho por este stack y siento como @Pikho que es una lástima que SE deje ir tanto talento y gente comprometida aunque ya no espero nada de ellos. Gracias a ti por todo.

Comment: Thank you for serving the community.  I hope that you get the rest and peace that you need.  I can well understand the exhaustion that you're suffering from.

Comment: Tú y yo hemos hablado suficiente de este tema en el chat de moderadores. Así que simplemente repetiré una de las cosas que te dije. Aprovecha para ver las cosas con perspectiva y para organizar prioridades. Gracias por haberme guiado en mis primeros pasos como moderador, tu ayuda ha sido inestimable. Ve, y buena suerte.

Comment: I take a few days off SE and everything goes kaplooie.  What happened?  Could someone please write up a brief, neutral "The Story So Far" here?  I am facing several tough deadlines so I don't have much time to dig around.  I need people's help to understand what happened here -- please.  I've read what's in La Tertulia for the last few days, but there's some slang I don't understand, and most importantly, for the life of me, I can't figure out how the whole thing started.  Oh jeesh, this is the last thing we needed, two important members of the site falling out with each other, and leaving.

Comment: @fedorqui Te recuerdo como el primero, o tal vez el único, que me dio una cálida bienvenida (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19571/ya-que-no-es-extranjerismo-qu%c3%a9-es-puenting-gramaticalmente-como-palabra-con/19573#19573). Desconozco qué te ha llevado a esta decisión, pero seguramente la habrás tomado con buen criterio. La "expulsión de talentos" ocurre en todos lados. Una pena. ¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: I was reviewing the Meta list of moderators who have stepped down today, and I saw your name listed there.  I've now reread your post here, and am now thinking that maybe I misunderstood your announcement.  Was the personal conflict with walen sort of a triggering event?  Was your decision mainly based on the recent problems with poor management from above?  That's what it looks like at Meta.SE. // Anyway, I wish you the best for your "retirement."  Well deserved after a long, productive stint as moderator.

Answer (score 10):

Gracias por dedicar tu tiempo y esfuerzo a las tareas de moderación.

Sé mejor que nadie que le has dedicado muchas horas a asegurarte de que el stack estuviese libre de problemas (a veces incluso robándole horas al sueño) y que le has dedicado mucho esfuerzo, volcándote en el stack como si fuera un proyecto personal.

Tu legado y tus contribuciones como moderador no nos pasan desapercibidas. Gracias por liderar y predicar con el ejemplo.

Gracias por muchos momentos compartidos.