# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: What is the purpose of this question itself? Just an announcement? Or is there any particular use case for answers here?

Comment: @wimi I think it is intended to cross-link to the main site so people who only visit one site see the election.

Comment: @mdewey but the main site already has a red link to the actual [election page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)...

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add here that there are many people who are contributing to this site and making my life as moderator considerably easier. People who would do great as moderators here. I know there can be many concerns given the current situation about what implies being a moderator. If anyone is just thinking about it and wants to know a bit more about what the moderator job actually is but do not want to make it public yet, please contact me by any means (I can't talk for [the former moderators](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3188/12637), but I suppose you can also try to talk with them for a wider perspective). I will try to answer any question as soon as possible, as long as my job and private life allow me.

This site needs you. I need you.

Comment: Enlazo a [Pregunta para los mods actuales: ¿qué supone para vosotros ser moderador de Spanish.SE?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3172/5481) (septiembre 2019) que viene a ser una breve explicación de lo que para quienes éramos moderadores por aquel entonces suponía ser moderar en este Stack. Bastantes cosas han cambiado desde entonces (y se abrieron hilos de discusión en meta sobre las mismas). Creo que los antiguos mods todavía tenemos en nuestro perfil instrucciones de cómo contactarnos en privado, por si alguien quisiese o necesitase hacerlo.