# How would the community feel about me running for moderator?

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

### Update:

I just posted [my nomination](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-36849). Thanks for the encouraging words!

---

**Let's be clear: I am not an old-timer (I have been here for 10 months), and there are other, much more experienced users that would be much more suited for the moderator role than me**.

Those users, however, do not seem to feel motivated to run for a moderator position, for different reasons to which they are of course entitled. We have therefore only Charlie as a moderator who does all the work, and both [JNat (from SE)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4391/24236) and [Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4385/24236) have clearly stated that we need more moderators. It is also not fair to leave all the responsibility to only one volunteer.

If the more experienced users confirm that they are not motivated to moderate, I would be willing to step up for this role, but **only if the community wants me**. Considering [the way the election will run](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4387/24236), it looks like a nomination would directly give me the role independently of how the voting goes, so I need to know this before deciding to nominate myself.

So here I ask you all: **would you support me as a moderator?** If there is enough support, I will nominate myself. If not, I won't. No hard feelings either way.

You can look at [my answers to the candidate Q&A](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4395/24236), which will hopefully help you form an opinion. I am looking forward to opinions, questions, and constructive criticism.

Comment: Llevas pocos meses en el sitio pero has demostrado sobradamente una madurez como usuario, un conocimiento y una curiosidad (tanto por la parte Meta como la parte del sitio en sí) que te hacen validísimo como posible moderador. Cuenta con mi voto. (De hecho en mis quinielas mentales te imaginaba de candidato)

Comment: Coincido con @fedorqui, yo todavía tenía la esperanza de que tú fueras uno de los candidatos. Me alegra que te hayas decidido a dar el paso, y cuenta con mi apoyo también.

Comment: I understand and respect your reasons for not posting a nomination without getting a feel for how the community would feel, but I'd also encourage you to to put your nomination up in the meantime regardless — there's space for discussion there (nomination threads have a comment section) _and_ here, and hopefully more people running incentivizes _more_ people to run. You can always withdraw your nomination before the election moves on to the next stage for any reason.

Comment: If you do so, I'd recommend posting your questionnaire answers on the actual questionnaire post — the discussion you want to hold here can pretty much be held there. You'd be welcome to keep this post here as a more general discussion, though, if you feel it'd help with visibility. I'd also defer to @Charlie on whether to feature it or not in that case.

Comment: @JNat good point about the possibility of withdrawing the nomination. I did not want to throw my nomination out there without any prior announcement. If no strong objections arise, I will post my nomination by the end of the day. To all: please make an effort not to laugh at my "candidate score" ;). It is going to be pretty ridiculous, but there was virtually no time in 10 months to accumulate all those reviews, edits, etc.

Comment: I'm not a regular here, so I can't really have an opinion about this particular discussion. But as a mod on another SE site, I can only encourage you to post a proper nomination, no matter how the other candidates will be, especially since you like the site and want to keep it running. The worst thing you might get is backlash or opposition from some of the users (that's how the real-life election goes too), but the better thing is that you have a determination to run for the better of the site and its community. At the very least, two is better than one!