# Acerca de localismos en el Código de conducta

Tags: discusión, respuestas, código-de-conducta

First question here!

Tengo una duda, desarrollo primero en español y luego hago un translate to English y la divido en tres partes: datos, problema y sugerencia. Es un caso particular del sitio.

---

El total de hispanoparlantes según el [Instituto Cervantes](https://www.cervantes.es/sobre_instituto_cervantes/prensa/2019/noticias/presentacion_anuario_madrid.htm#:%7E:text=Un%20total%20de%20580%20millones,mundo%20por%20n%C3%BAmero%20de%20hablantes.) son 580 millones. Los porcentajes respecto a cantidad de individuos por país son muy diferentes. Por ejemplo, en España hay 46 millones, similar a Argentina. Pero en México la cifra se dispara: más de ciento treinta millones. Esto sumado al resto de países que hablan español, dejan a España en un porcentaje relativamente medio/bajo. [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Pa%C3%ADses_donde_el_espa%C3%B1ol_es_idioma_oficial).

Sin hacer una búsqueda de datos, con solo visualizar el mapa de influencia podríamos decir que España aparece solo en aproximadamente menos de un 10% del total, contando solo países con uso oficial/semi-oficial del idioma:

[image]

---

Leyendo el Código de Conducta de SES, específicamente [How do I write a good answer?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), los puntos tratados son genéricos a como responder en SE, pero creo que esta comunidad requiere un apartado especial, y me refiero a los localismos. Hay términos que siendo correctos y válidos en España son indescifrables en el resto del mundo hispanohablante. Como ejemplo, flip-flop en Argentina es *ojota* y en España este término no existe, es *chancla*. Esto puede llevar a muchas confusiones al OP que realiza la pregunta y desea saber el nombre real.

---

Sabiendo que hay muchos usuarios ibéricos que responden, no sé el porcentaje de globales, según mi parecer, en el listado de *How do I write a good answer?* debería existir el apartado de:

> Si tu respuesta es acerca de un término local o tienes dudas acerca del uso global, por favor indica la procedencia.

Tal como sucede con los enlaces.

---

*English: data, problem, and suggestion*

It's a particular case of the site.

The total number of Spanish speakers according to the [Cervantes Institute](https://www.cervantes.es/sobre_instituto_cervantes/prensa/2019/noticias/presentacion_anuario_madrid.htm#:%7E:text=Un%20total%20de%20580%20millones,mundo%20por%20n%C3%BAmero%20de%20hablantes.) is 580 million. The percentages regarding the number of individuals per country are very different. For example, in Spain, there are 46 million, similar to Argentina. But in Mexico the figure skyrockets: more than one hundred and thirty million. This, added to the rest of the countries that speak Spanish, leaves Spain in a relatively medium/low percentage. [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Pa%C3%ADses_donde_el_espa%C3%B1ol_es_idioma_oficial)

Without doing a data search, just by viewing the influence map, we could say Spain only appears in approximately less than 10% of the total, counting only countries with official/semi-official use of the language (see the image above).

---

Reading the SES Code of Conduct, specifically, [How do I write a good answer?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), the points discussed are generic to how to answer in SE, but I think this community requires a special section, and I'm referring to localisms. There are terms that, being correct and valid in Spain, are indecipherable in the rest of the Spanish-speaking world. As an example, the flip-flop in Argentina is *ojota* and in Spain, this term does not exist, it is *chancla*. This can lead to a lot of confusion for the OP who asks a question and wants to know the real name.

---

Knowing that there are many Iberian answering users, I don't know the global percentage, in my opinion, in the list of *How do I write a good answer?* there should be a section:

> If your answer is about a local term or you have doubts about its global use, please indicate the origin.

As happens with the links.

---

Comment: Me parece muy buena idea.

Comment: Desafortunadamente, los moderadores no podemos editar la sección [answer]. Solo podemos editar [ask]. Para editar otras partes del *help center*, tiene que intervenir un empleado de SE (un CM). Para que eso tenga éxito, tiene que haber un claro consenso de la comunidad (no sé qué definición de "claro consenso" aplicarán los CM) y la propuesta tiene que ser clara.

Comment: La frase que propones no encaja bien en el estilo de [answer], donde cada sección es un párrafo con un título en negrita. Voy a intentar escribir la propuesta con ese estilo, a ver si podemos escalar esto cuando estemos de acuerdo en el texto. Tengo que advertir ya de que, debido a la conocida poca participación en Meta, no sé si conseguiremos que apliquen el cambio.

Comment: Ok, bueno, es solo una sugerencia, tampoco tiene tanta relevancia. Lo de la escasa participación también lo percibo, estas cosas suelen tener solución, pero muchas veces no depende de los usuarios.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674) y [Which elements of the frontpage can be customized per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378042/209901).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion for the wording of the potential new section of the [How to answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page of the Help center. This section would go immediately after the section **Provide context for links**:

> ### Localize region-specific words or phrases
>
> Spanish is spoken in many countries, and some words or phrases are only used in some areas, or have different meanings across regions. This can lead to confusion if readers use your proposed term in a place where it is not understood. If your answer is about a region-specific term or you have doubts about its global use, please indicate where the term is used.

Feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Looks ok, but "regions" is repeated six times

Comment: @Danielillo yes, there was definitely room for improvement there. I have made it less repetitive.