# Proposals re the site description

Tags: discusión, ámbito, centro-de-ayuda

Take a look at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour.  At the beginning there is a site-specific description.  This also shows up at https://stackexchange.com/sites.  Here's what our site description says:

> Q&A for linguists, teachers, students and Spanish language enthusiasts in general wanting to discuss the finer points of the language.

This is longer than for other sites.  First, I think it could be shortened to

> Q&A for linguists, teachers, students and Spanish language enthusiasts.

Here's what we have at  [Help > Asking > On-topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> The Spanish Language Stack Exchange is for linguists, teachers, students and Spanish language enthusiasts in general.

I propose to take out "in general."  This is an empty filler phrase that takes up space unnecessarily.  (And filler phrases like this and "very" can actually dilute the message.)

Comment: Related: [Proposal: change site description to “Linguists, teachers, students and enthusiasts”](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2741/1674)