# ¿Por qué la pregunta "Technical translation for 'stream'" tuvo tanto 'éxito'?

Tags: discusión

¿Qué tiene una pregunta como [ésta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26286/6915) para ser vista 1k en un día, con 9 votos y 5 respuestas?

Desde mi punto de vista es poco atractiva y referida a un ámbito súper restringido. Con todo respeto por walen, por supuesto, él sabe a lo que me refiero: no es de un asunto "importante" del español y finalmente sabemos que nadie va a necesitar traducir "stream" en la vida real.

Yo tengo preguntas interesantísimas :) que han sido vistas 200 veces en 2 años.

Digo más arriba que es poco atractiva, pero claramente estoy equivocado. Lo que tiene de especial esa pregunta a lo mejor sirve para orientar al stack a ganar más participación.

Comment: A veces es un completo misterio porqué una pregunta puede caer en gracia. Igual depende de la hora a la que la publiques, y los usuarios más activos da la casualidad de que tienen tiempo para responder, publican 2 o 3 respuestas y apareces en las HNQ. Puede ser por el tema (algo que a _mucha_ gente le parezca _muy_ interesante, en contraposición a algo que es _terriblemente interesante_, pero para unos pocos). Quizá no sea una pregunta importante sobre gramática o tiempos verbales, pero la audiencia del stack viene a veces de SO (es técnica...).

Comment: Como curiosidad, si te pasas por el stack de ciencia ficción, una de las preguntas más votadas es ["De quién son estos calzoncillos?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68005/32339) que báscicamente es una pregunta tipo identificación sobre el logo o emblema de un personaje. Entre la curiosidad, lo divertido del asunto y similar pues mira, unos 200 votos y 25.000 visitas (eso sí, en cuatro años). Una pregunta poco ortodoxa y quizá con muy poco valor, pero entretenida y curiosa. Entiendo que por eso la visita mucha gente, no solo los fans o seguidores de un tag o franquicia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como autor de la pregunta creo que me toca responder :)

Uno de los principales factores que ayudan al éxito de una pregunta, en casi cualquier stack, es el entrar en las [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), donde (como sabes) se muestran las preguntas mas [populares / candentes / actuales / de moda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22248/translation-of-hotness-points-as-used-by-the-hot-network-questions-algorithm).

Ojo al nombre: *Hot* Network Questions. No *Quality* Network Questions, ni *Important* Network Questions. Solo "hot".
Guste o no, esta lista es un escaparate de preguntas que están registrando mucha actividad tanto en votos como en respuestas. Se da por hecho que, si la pregunta no es adecuada para el stack, el propio stack se encargará de votarla y cerrarla (con lo cual desaparece de la lista) pero, por lo demás, suele ser un buen reflejo de preguntas que interesan a la comunidad en general, más allá de que a algunos nos puedan parecer mejores o peores.

---

Y aquí debo romper una lanza en favor de mi pregunta.

Ya lo dices tú mismo, pero **quiero recalcar que la afirmación de que *«no es un asunto "importante"»* es bastante subjetiva**.
Puede que para ti no sea importante, pero hay muchas personas que ven importante disponer siempre de una alternativa en español a tanto anglicismo técnico que permea su día a día. De hecho, en cierta manera, pocas cosas hay más importantes para el español que encontrar maneras de seguir usándolo.
Y en ese sentido, no creo que mi pregunta sea peor que [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-should-i-translate-table-as-in-a-data-table) o [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/translation-of-bug-to-spanish) o, sin irnos tan lejos, [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20113/en-un-contexto-de-expresiones-regulares-c%C3%B3mo-se-puede-traducir-match) o [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/traducci%C3%B3n-correcta-de-stage-y-staging-en-el-contexto-de-git) o [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13445/how-would-you-translate-dashboard-from-a-web-application-point-of-view), todas similares en ámbito; o que otras en contextos [ligeramente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/c%C3%B3mo-traducir-shadow-como-verbo) o [totalmente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21721/c%C3%B3mo-se-le-llama-a-un-grupo-de-flechas-disparadas) distintos.

En cuanto a la otra afirmación de que *«nadie va a necesitar traducir "stream" en la vida real»*, siento decir que **tampoco es cierto**. En la misma pregunta tienes el contraejemplo:

> Today, however, I tried to replace it with a Spanish term instead, and I felt a bit puzzled.

Esto no es un cuento que me invento para darle ambiente a la pregunta: realmente quise usar una palabra en español para no andar todo el rato diciendo *estrim*, y no supe cuál usar. De ahí el hacer la pregunta en el stack.

---

Rota la lanza, continúo.

Las HNQ, como decía, suelen dar bombo a preguntas que tienen bastante movimiento en un stack. Una vez que entras en las HNQ, los votos y visitas, es decir el "éxito" como tú dices, llegan casi solos.
Entonces (y ya respondiéndote), **¿por qué mi pregunta llegó a las HNQ?** Creo que por lo siguiente:

- Es un **tema cercano**. Casi todos hemos llegado aquí vía Stack Overflow o similar. Se da por hecho que a todos los usuarios del stack nos gusta la lengua española, claro, pero no tiene por qué ser al mismo nivel. Para muchos, la programación es un tema que les resulta más familiar que otros como la fonética o la etimología. **Esto hace que mi pregunta les resulte más interesante** que otras que los más veteranos (o los menos técnicos) podamos considerar más importantes o más trabajadas.
- Es una **pregunta sencilla**. Para responderla no hace falta tirar de CORDE, ni consultar varias fuentes. No hace falta conocer lo que significa clítico ni la diferencia entre bilabial oclusivo y africado, ni citar la *Nueva Ortografía* ni saber, literalmente, latín. Basta con que entiendas cuál es el concepto que se quiere transmitir y propongas una palabra para ello. **Esto hace que más gente se vea capaz de responder**.
- Está **escrita en inglés**. Lo cual ofrece dos ventajas:

  - **Hace que sea más accesible** para aquellos que todavía no controlan el español, pues les resulta más fácil comprender la pregunta y al mismo tiempo les deja claro que pueden responder en inglés si les resulta más fácil.
  - **Permite la entrada en las HNQ**. Las preguntas en idiomas distintos del inglés están prohibidas en las HNQ porque la gente se queja, precisamente, de que no las entiende. Escribiendo en inglés evito ese filtro y facilito que mi pregunta llegue a más personas.

Nótese que, salvo el último punto, todo lo indicado es *interno al stack*. Antes de llegar a las HNQ y ser visible al resto de la red, mi pregunta recibió varios votos positivos y respuestas de usuarios nuestros que, supuestamente, la encontraron suficientemente interesante como para votarla y/o responderla. Para conseguir eso, creo que los factores determinantes son los que he resaltado: temas cercanos y preguntas sencillas y accesibles.

**¿Significa esto que debemos orientar el stack a preguntas sencillas, traducciones, temas técnicos y demás? ¡No, por Dios!**

Afortunadamente, Spanish.SE es una comunidad donde tienen cabida desde estudiantes y simples aficionados del idioma, hasta profesores, académicos y lingüistas de nivel ([y así nos presentamos ante el mundo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/proposal-change-site-description-to-linguists-teachers-students-and-enthusia)).
El nivel y rango de conocimientos que aglutinan los usuarios de este sitio es asombroso, y por suerte disponemos de esta plataforma para plantear dudas de todo tipo, desde [las más sencillas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-should-i-ask-someone-to-repeat-something-theyve-said) hasta [las más complicadas de responder](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).
Sí, es posible que a muchos usuarios "nuevos" les resulten más interesantes las preguntas de traducción técnica que las preguntas sobre p. ej. alófonos... al principio. Pero no por ello el stack debe eliminar las preguntas sobre alófonos: es importante que esas preguntas y sus respuestas estén ahí, para quien quiera profundizar más en su conocimiento del lenguaje.

Alguien puede decir que no es justo que las preguntas más sencillas sean las que obtengan mayor "recompensa", y es cierto. Iniciativas como el [concurso de mejores respuestas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/propuesta-concurso-de-las-mejores-respuestas-de-cada-trimestre) intentan paliar eso :)
Por lo demás, creo que ambos tipos de preguntas pueden convivir, y es importante que lo hagan para tener una comunidad viva y sana.

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente es el efecto [HNQ](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), como ya te han dicho. Por mi experiencia también me ha pasado lo que tú dices: a veces hago preguntas que me parecen muy curradas e interesantes y tras un año apenas llegan a 200 visitas y tienen muy pocos votos y respuestas, y en cambio otras que son más de tipo trivia, que realmente no hacen que aprendas más allá de la curiosidad que te explican, acaban con miles de votos y visitas.

Cuando una pregunta entra en la lista de "preguntas calentitas", eso hace que aparezca en la portada de sitios con cientos de miles de visitas diarias, como Stack Overflow. Con que apenas un 1% de los visitantes del sitio sienta curiosidad por la pregunta, ya tienes asegurado un chorreo de visitas y, si el usuario está registrado, de votos. Me pasó hace poco en el sitio de English Language and Usage: hice [una pregunta sobre un carácter extraño](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/443346/280768) que me encontré en un texto (y que, si lo piensas, no tenía nada que ver con el idioma inglés), entró en las HNQ y acabó con más de 10K visitas (cosa que aquí todavía no he conseguido) y más de 80 votos en apenas tres días.

Para que una pregunta entre en las HNQ y reciba ese impulso tiene que cumplir algunos requisitos:

- Que esté redactada en inglés en su mayor parte (en el título creo que se admiten hasta dos palabras en otros idiomas).
- Que consiga rápidamente un par de votos positivos y una o dos respuestas que también estén bien votadas. Esto depende del sitio concreto: los sitios con menos visitas diarias tienen más opciones de salir en las HNQ.

La pregunta de los *streams* cumplió con ambas condiciones. Ten en cuenta que muchos de los usuarios de los sitios de Stack Exchange somos programadores, por lo que estas preguntas técnicas solemos responderlas aunque sea por pura curiosidad. La cabra tira al monte, como se suele decir.

Comment: Para los curiosos, la fórmula completa para la confección de la lista de "preguntas calentitas" (me gustó la expresión) está en [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/209901). Las seis primeras horas se va acumulando potencia y a partir de allí debe mantenerse el influjo de votos y respuestas si se quiere seguir en la lista.

Answer (score 1):

Inspirado por [Breaking the HNQ feedback loop on bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286020/287826) y https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286051/287826, propongo que los moderadores pongan un banner rosado sobre las preguntas "calientes" con un mensaje más o menos así:

> Welcome! If this is your first visit to Spanish Language SE, perhaps you'd like to visit (link) this list of some of our favorite questions.

Comment: Propuesta interesante. ¿Te refieres a enlazar con la lista de preguntas canónicas?

Comment: No, habria que desarrollar una nueva lista de preguntas que llamen la atencion pero que *nosotros* podamos escoger, en lugar de ser *una sola* pregunta *escogida por un algoritmo imbecil*.

Comment: Uf, no me convence. Lo que sí puede decidirse es qué pregunta sale en [tour].